# How to install nodejs dependencies on windows 8.1?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

How do you install the nodejs dependencies on windows 8.1? I have nodejs installed under c:/program files/nodejs

When I issue the `npm install` command I get the following errors:

```
> cd myproject
Current working directory is 'C:\wamp\www\laravel\myproject'.

> "C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" install
npm WARN package.json @ No repository field.

> node-sass@2.0.1 install C:\wamp\www\laravel\myproject\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js


> node-sass@2.0.1 postinstall C:\wamp\www\laravel\myproject\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

`win32-x64-node-0.12` exists; testing
Binary is fine; exiting
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! path C:\wamp\www\laravel\myproject\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\gulp-ruby-sass\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-stream\node_modules\unique-stream\node_modules\es6-set\node_modules\d\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT, open 'C:\wamp\www\laravel\myproject\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\gulp-ruby-sass\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-stream\node_modules\unique-stream\node_modules\es6-set\node_modules\d\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\wamp\www\laravel\myproject\npm-debug.log
```

Can any one provide instructions on how to get this working on windows 8.1? The `npm install` command is issued whilst in the following directory `C:\wamp\www\laravel\myproject` - the directory has the following package.json file:

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
      "gulp": "^3.8.8",
      "laravel-elixir": "*"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears npm is having trouble finding the package.json file within one of the dependencies of your dependencies.

It worked fine for me using your package.json file and running `npm install` so I'd suggest deleting the node_modules folder and running `npm install` command again.

When running `npm install` npm looks for the package.json in the current directory, it appears that the error is due to no package.json file in the directory where you're running the command.

You can also run `npm install {package}` if you don't have a package.json file to install a package in the current directory. Add the `-g` option to install the package globally in the node core directory.

Comment: please see edited post which shows the directory in which the npm install command is issued. The directory also has a package.json file but I still get the these errors?

Comment: Deleted the  node_modules directory under `C:\wamp\www\laravel\myproject\node_modules` and re ran `npm install` but still getting the same errors. Is there something that needs to be done with the environment variables on windows 8.1?

Comment: looks like the issue is with installing laravel-elixir - `node_module` folder has no folder for `laravel-elixir`. Are you running the `npm install` command on a windows 8.1 platform?

Comment: Yes, ran `npm install` on Windows 8.1. You may want to reinstall Node/npm.